# Visual Studio Express controls overlap in design view

Tags: forms, visual-studio, visual-studio-express

I have a form in Visual Studio 2010 Express that contains two controls in the same location.  While designing, I need to see each one individually without having to move them.  How do I do this?  The one on "top" always displays in design view even after selecting the "bottom" one in the "Properties" pane.

Comment: Before you post, summarize the problem and provide details and example for that to describe what you’ve tried.

Comment: Right Click the Control and "Send to Back" to get to the control below it...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Having worked with VS before, I did try that. :)  But it doesn't work for my labels.  I have several "doubled-up" labels.  The ones on the bottom still stay on the bottom.  I want to drag them around for ideal placement, and setting the Location property is a bit annoying.